# :after span positioning differs between Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I have a problem when creating an HTML-input with a symbol (e.g. money) attached to it. Chrome and Firefox seem to render the alignment of the "money-symbol" differently.

The HTML

```
<div class="inputlabel">
  <label>
    Some Label
  </label>
  <span class="inputlabel-span input-symbol-euro">
    <input type="text"/>
  </span>
</div>
```

The CSS

```
.inputlabel label{ display: block}
.inputlabel input{ line-height:50px;}

.inputlabel-span {
  position: relative;
}
.inputlabel-span input {
  padding:0;
  width:200px; 
  border:none;
}
.inputlabel-span:after {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  content: "€";
  right: 0px;
}
```

Link to the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g0ztgcw8/9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because of the element spacing of putting an `input` inside a `span`. You can fix this by commenting out the white space between the end of the input element and the closing `span` tag:

```css
.inputlabel label{ display: block}
.inputlabel input{ line-height:50px;}

.inputlabel-span {
  position: relative;
}
.inputlabel-span input {
  padding:0;
  width:200px; 
  border: none;
}
.inputlabel-span::after {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  content: "€";
  right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="inputlabel">
  <label>
    Some Label
  </label>
  <span class="inputlabel-span input-symbol-euro">
    <input type="text"/><!--
--></span>
</div>

<p></p>
<div style="width:200px;background-color:red;">
This div has 200px
</div>
```

You'll see no change in Chrome and the code will display the Euro symbol inside the input element on Firefox correctly now.

Comment: whoah now that is really weird - but it's working :)

Comment: Can this also be achieved using plain css or do I really have to comment out the white space?

Comment: @MikeS You can use CSS styles like Seika suggested, though it's more convoluted/less readable. The simplest method to implement and to understand when you read the code is to just use a comment; that will always mean "I want to eliminate white space between these two elements".

Answer (score 1):

If you add a border around your span, you will see, in chrome it has only an small height, because the span is in `display:inline` 
Force the span to be `display:inline-block`  and change the rest of your code at your convenience, you won't need to make some trick in all browser to fix that, it will be the same in all browser.

Comment: Yes I tried this one, too. But then I would have the problem of vertically aligning the euro-symbol. However I don't know the size of the font since it can be configured within in my app

Answer (score 0):

That those browsers display it different, is because of the different rendering order of inline elements in those browsers. First positioning then render the "€" in one browser, or the other way around in the other browser. Try giving it a width, like `.inputlabel-span:after { width: 12px; }` or something similar.

Putting `input` tags inside a span is rather bad practice by the way and another reason for this behaviour. You should at least add `display: inline-block` to this ***span***, if you want to keep this DOM structure.
Your ***:after*** element would then need an additional `top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%)` to position it vertically centered.

I also recommend to always define `* { box-sizing: border-box }`, but this has nothing to do in particular with your question.

Comment: Giving a width to the :after doesn't work. Though the euro symbol is aligned more to the left there is still a difference comparing the distance in firefox and chrome

Comment: As I mentioned the the span is another reason. I set `display: inline-block` to the ***span*** and `top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%);` to the ***:after*** and it worked for me: https://jsfiddle.net/g0ztgcw8/12/